# Node menu link is inconsistent with active trail when multiple items point to the same node

Tags: drupal-modules

> When same node is applied to multiple menu items then *inActiveTrail* is
>   coming true for the first one instead of the current menu clicked one.

For testing purpose in a drupal 8 site create multi-level menu and apply below code and it will output current active menu array. Just omit `$currentlinkId` and `$parameters->setRoot` to see `inActiveTrail` in array.

```
$menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
$menu_name = 'main';

$parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);
$currentLinkId = reset($parameters->activeTrail);
$parameters->setRoot($currentLinkId);
$tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);

// Transform the tree using the manipulators you want.
$manipulators = array(
    // Only show links that are accessible for the current user.
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
    // Use the default sorting of menu links.
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
);
$tree = $menu_tree->transform($tree, $manipulators);
kint($tree);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the feedback from drupal forum , from below link.
[Drupal.org forum link](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2018-11-06/node-menu-link-is-inconsistent-with)